# LTspice measuring drain current when certain values of Vds and Vgs are reached

Tags: ltspice, simulation

I'm new to LTspice and I need to measure all the possible values of the drain current of a JFET when certain combinations of Vds and Vgs values are reached. That is, I need to record specific points of the output curve of the JFET.

For example: Vgs will vary from 0 to -5V in -1V steps; for each Vgs value, Vds will vary from 0 to 10V in 0.5V steps; for each Vds in each Vgs I need to record the drain current.

This could be done with nested .step directives if Vds was a voltage source (so I could use a {Vds} param), but I have this circuit instead:

[image]

Any idea is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, read up on the .MEAS card. Then play with it. Its results will appear on the View/Spice Error Log menu option. This may be what you want -- not sure, though. But it has a lot of options and a lot of capability. So probably it will help.

Comment: What's the purpose of this exercise? If you want to know how the JFET behaves, just remove R2 and apply VDD directly to the drain.

Comment: Sounds like you want the JFET characteristic curves.  This is usually done by doing a DC sweep with both of your voltage sources.  Like the previous comment stated, remove R2 to acheive this.

Comment: Also see `<My Documents>/LTspiceXVII/examples/Educational/IGBT.asc` for a way of doing a DC sweep. It's about an IGBT, but it can be used for any transistor.

Comment: @SteKulov, I needed the numeric values from specific points at the characteristic curves. I found a workaround and posted it as a answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the closest procedure I've got to the fully automated approach:

I've created a parameter called VGG for the gate voltage source, then I've stepped it throught the desired points:

```
.step param VGG list 0 -0.5 -1.0 -2.0 -3.0 -4.0 -5.0
```

Then for each desired Vds value, I've created a corresponding variable Id_ using the .meas:

```
.meas DC Id_<x> FIND I(R2) WHEN V(VDS)=<value>
```

As I needed 7 different Vds values, I had to write 7 different .meas lines (thus 7 Id_ variables). But I guess it's better to write 7 lines than writing 49 lines.

Comment: I think you misunderstood why we were asking about R2 in the comments.  Based on your answer, it's unnecessary and you should use `.meas DC Id_<x> FIND ID(J1) WHEN V(VDS)=<value>`.